# How to handle tail recursion with futures

Tags: scala

Consider the following example

```
  def futureFoo() = {
    Future.successful(true)
  }

  def recFoo(x: List[Int]): Unit = {
    if (x.isEmpty) return

    for {
      b <- futureFoo()
      v = getNewListOfValues(x.last)
      _ = recFoo(v)
    } yield b
  }
```

I need to wait for `futureFoo` to finish and only then call `recFoo` again. The problem is no matter what I try I get the following error:

```
discarded non-Unit value
```

I also tried to convert it into a while loop but because of the future I either get the same error or the while condition doesn't update because it must be updated in a `for comprehension` or `map`.

Any ideas on how to prevent that error?

Comment: Maybe `_ <- recFoo(v)`?

Comment: Why do you `yield b` when the method is supposed to return `Unit`?

Comment: @jwvh without it I get `illegal start of simple expression
  }`

Comment: @Bergi tried it, didn't help

Comment: Just use `flatMap` you don't need tail-recursion with `Futures`  they never blow up the stack. - Anyways, it would be good to properly explain what you are trying to do since right now the posted code is just a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: I'm doing processing with pagination, i.e. get a chunk of data and do some async stuff with it (futureFoo). With every iteration I fetch another page from the db (getNewListOfValues). Flatmap resulted in discarded non-unit value too. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @shinzou well you should not return `Unit`, rather you should return `Future[Unit]` so the caller has a `Future` that will be completed when all the batches are processed; if the caller wants to fire and forget that is up to them. - So your code should look like something like [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/d8zSwmunRU6HLMMOnunlgg). - Also, maybe you want to take a look at some streaming approaches like **AkkaStreams** or **fs2** for this kind of work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def recFoo(x: List[Int]): Unit =
  if (x.nonEmpty)
    futureFoo().foreach(_ => recFoo(getNewListOfValues(x.last)))
```

Comment: I'm getting 
could not optimize @tailrec annotated method xxx: it contains a recursive call not in tail position

Comment: That's a new and different question. There is no `@tailrec` in the posted code.

Comment: You're right I forgot to add it, but that was the intention.

Comment: Do you think it's necessary?

Comment: To get clear and correct answers it is necessary to ask clear and complete questions.

Comment: yes you're right. What do you think would be better than, edit this question or ask another one?

Comment: This is not actually tail call if `@tailrec` doesn't accept.

Answer (score 1):

The specific reason that you are getting

> `discarded non-Unit value`

in your error message is that you have an expression after `return`.

Note that in Scala, the `return` keyword should **almost never** be used. Scala is an expression-oriented language; each block (such as a function body) evaluates to the value returned from the last line in the block.

So, for example, consider the following snippet:

```scala
val foo = {
  import scala.util.Random
  if (Random.nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
    17
  } else {
    "bar"
  }
}
```

Everything from `if` to the closing brace after `"bar"` is a single expression -- NOT a statement. Scala, in fact, does not **have** "if-statements" in the way that Java and other languages do. In particular, the compiler needs to infer a type for the name `foo`, and since `foo` could concretely be either the `Int` `17` or the `String` `"bar"`, that inferred type is the closest common ancestor of both `Int` and `String`, which is `Any`.

In your question, the last expression in the body of `recFoo` is the following:

```scala
for {
  b <- futureFoo()
  v = getNewListOfValues(x.last)
  _ = recFoo(v)
} yield b
```

What is the type of this expression? In many languages, `for` introduces a **statement**, but that's not true of Scala -- this is an **expression**, not a statement, and like all expressions it will have a value once we evaluate it. That value has type `Future[Unit]`, and like all non-`Unit` values, the compiler is warning you that you are discarding a value, which is (almost) always a mistake. (Why would you go to the trouble of producing a non-`Unit` value and then not make use of it?, goes the thinking.)